# What is the "recursive condition" of this code (Recursion in Java)

Tags: java, recursion

I am working on this problem and I do not understand the solution.

A screenshot of the problem is located at https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUtRk.png and quoted here:

> Assuming that parameter `n` is non-negative, what is the recursive
>   condition (which allows the recursive method to be called) of method
>   `mystery`?

```
public int mymestry( int n, int m )
{
    if ( n == 0 )
        return 0;
    if ( n == 1 )
        return m;
    return m + mymestry( n - 1, m );
}
```

Originally I thought the solution should be `n > 0`; but I am told the correct solution is `n >= 2`.

Why is `n >= 2` considered to be the correct solution rather than `n > 0`?

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: I do not see this condition in the code

Comment: @MaxZoom i returns for when `n` is one or zero

Comment: What do you mean by recursive condition? Do you mean what value of `n` will cause recursive call?

Comment: @Pshemo yes the solution was n>=2 I don't understand why ?

Comment: @AhmedHillal Again, I am not sure what you mean by *recursion condition*. If it is what condition needs to be met to make method call itself recursively then based on your code it is when n >= 2 (or n<0 but I suspect that this range should be excluded because it will generate wrong result, assuming that `mymestry` method should be responsible for multiplication). So if you use `n=0` your method will immediately return `0` without recursive call. Same for `n=1`, method will immediately return `m`. Only for positive values which are different than `1` and `2` method will recursively call itself.

Comment: @Pshemo OP didnt say to start from zero, OP says to start from one, `n>0` so OP is right

Comment: @Pshemo Thx Bro I got it ^_^

Comment: @Lrrr Yes, I know. I was just reading out lout what this method will do for its predefined non-recursive cases (its stop conditions) :)

Comment: @Pshemo Ok I misread your comment :)

Comment: @AhmedHillal did you read my answer?

Comment: @Lrrr yes dude I was but actually I don't understand you well but anyway thx for helping :)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the terminology you are using:

The "recursive condition" is the set of circumstances in which the function will call itself recursively to reduce the problem domain.  When this happens, a new function call is added to the stack and the call goes "deeper"

The "stopping condition" is the set of circumstances where the function will provide an answer directly (which will be fed back into any calling functions).  When this happens, the function calls previously added to the stack will receive answers and in turn provide answers back to their calling functions.  In other words, the stack is "unwinding" or getting "smaller".

Based on the code provided, if `n == 0` or `n == 1`, no recursion will occur.  Hence, `n > 0` does not necessarily satisfy the condition.  `n >= 2` will cause the function to be called recursively, so it represents the "recursive condition"

Answer (score 1):

Recursion is only needed when there is more then one element to process.
If there is one or zero elements then return.

Answer (score 0):

your `mymestry` function seems to multiple `n` and `m`, and of course you could start from 1 instead of two and change your function to:

```
public int mymestry (int n, int m)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    return m + mymestry(n-1, m);
}
```

but the one who wrote this code, consider `m*1` a trivial multiple and returns its value instead of calculating it.